SwiftUI view running twice
I have a view that draws some lines and filled circles. But to know the position of these lines I need to dynamically calculate them as they are being drawn.
I have two issues.
The first is that for some reason, the view code runs twice on the first load messing up the array lastYPos; but if I resize the window, the code runs once and it works fine.
The second is that I use "let _ = " to change the value of variables, and I believe that this is a bad practice, but I cannot think of a better way to do it.
struct LinesView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var t: Time?
    var xStep: CGFloat
    var yStep: CGFloat

var body: some View {
    if let t {
        let es = [someClass]
        let ar = [someClass]
        var ls: [Line] = []
        var lastYPos: [CGFloat] = []
        
        ZStack{
            ForEach(es) { e in
                let xPos = xStep * CGFloat(e.position)
                ForEach(ar.indices, id: \.self) { aIndex in
                    let arc = ar[aIndex]
                    let yPos = yStep * CGFloat(arcIndex + 1)
                    if !lastYPos.indices.contains(aIndex) {
                        let _ = lastYPos.insert(yPos, at: aIndex)
                    }
                    if e.position > 1 {
                        if e.position == 2 {
                            let yStart = yStep * CGFloat(isPrevShared.1 + 1)
                            drawJoiningLine(arc: arc, xPos: xPos, xStep: xStep, yStart: yStart, yEnd: yPos, lines: &ls, position: e.position)
                            let _ = setVariables(xStart: xPos - xStep, yStart: yStart, xEnd: xPos, yEnd: yPos, arcIndex: arcIndex, lines: &ls, arcYPos: &lastYPos)
                        } else {
                            drawJoiningLine(arc: arc, xPos: xPos, xStep: xStep, yStart: lastYPos[aIndex], yEnd: yPos, lines: &ls, position: e.position)
                            let _ = setVariables(xStart: xPos - xStep, yStart: lastYPos[aIndex], xEnd: xPos, yEnd: yPos, arcIndex: aIndex, lines: &ls, arcYPos: &lastYPos)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func drawJoiningLine(a: SomeClass, xPos: CGFloat, xStep: CGFloat, yStart: CGFloat, yEnd: CGFloat, lines: inout [Line], position: Int) -> some View {
    print("Drawing Line for arc:\(a.name), event position:\(position)")
    let overlappingLines = lines.filter {
        ($0.start == CGPoint(x: xPos - xStep, y: yStart) && $0.end == CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yEnd)) ||
        ($0.start == CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yEnd) && $0.end == CGPoint(x: xPos - xStep, y: yStart))
    }.count
    let width = 40
    let lineWidth = yStart == yEnd ? CGFloat(width) / CGFloat(overlappingLines + 1) : CGFloat(width) / CGFloat(overlappingLines + 2)
    let newColor = Color(NSColor(hex: a.color))
    return Canvas(rendersAsynchronously: false) { contex, size in
        if yStart != yEnd || position == 2 {
            let xStart = xPos - xStep
            contex.fill(
                Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xStart - (lineWidth/2), y: yStart - (lineWidth/2)), size: CGSize(width: lineWidth, height: lineWidth)))
                , with: .color(newColor))
        }
        contex.fill(
            Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xPos - (lineWidth/2), y: yEnd - (lineWidth/2)), size: CGSize(width: lineWidth, height: lineWidth)))
            , with: .color(newColor))
        contex.stroke(Path{ path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos - xStep, y: yStart))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yEnd))
        }, with: .color(newColor), lineWidth: lineWidth)
    }
}

func setVariables(xStart: CGFloat, yStart: CGFloat, xEnd: CGFloat, yEnd: CGFloat, arcIndex: Int, lines: inout [Line], lastYPos: inout [CGFloat]) {
    let line = Line(start: CGPoint(x: xStart, y: yStart), end: CGPoint(x: xEnd, y: yEnd))
    lines.append(line)
    lastYPos[arcIndex] = yEnd
}

}`

Yup, the body isn’t for doing work it is for displaying stuff. Use task or onAppear if you have to do work there

...I believe that this is a bad practice, certainly is.
Note, ForEach should not be thought of as a normal for loop.
Declare things like your @State private var ls: [Line] = [] etc...
in the View not the body, and change those
in functions and places like .onAppear or .task as mentioned.
